# Bash: how to print the string /*

Tags: bash

I need to read a file and print out most of the lines exactly as is. I'm doing this like so:

```
while read line; do
  do stuff if line meets requirements 
  otherwise print it as is to output file like so:
  echo $line >> $
done <<< "$(cat "$SOURCE_TESTBENCH")"
```

Problem is some lines contain stuff like this line

```
/*  // From testbench
```

Which is printed out as a listing of the folders from /. Indeed this simple snippet does not work as expected:

```
line=/*
echo $line
```

Instead of printing /* like I want it to, it prints the list of directories.

How can I print the read line EXACTLY like it is on the original file?

Comment: Use double quotes around the variable: `echo "$line"`.

Comment: Did you try, `echo "$line"`?

Comment: I thought I had. Obviously I have done something wrong as this solved my problem. Thank you. One of you should post it as an answer so I might accept it.

Comment: Don't use a here string when a simple input redirection `< "$SOURCE_TESTBENCH"` is appropriate.

Comment: See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

Comment: To read lines exactly as they appear in the file: `while IFS= read -r line; do ...; done < filename`

Answer (score 3):

To print a string containing the contents of a variable, use `printf`:

```
printf '%s\n' "$line"
```

The `\n` appends a newline, which is of course optional.

The usual rules surrounding parameter expansion apply. Always use double quotes around your variables.

Answer (score 2):

Quick guide:

- `echo $var` should print out what's inside of the variable
- `echo '$var'` will print out exactly what's inside the single quotes
- `echo "$var"` will print out exactly what's contained inside the variable (without executing it)

However, the unquoted style `echo $var` *is subject to* filename expansion and word splitting, whereas `echo "$var"` will suppress this.

So, for your needs, definitely `echo "$var"` will be safe.

Comment: `echo $var` will not execute what's in var

Comment: My bad...edited as much. I wonder what was triggering the printing the list of directories.

Comment: You'll want to review http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions -- after parameter expansion, unquoted values are subject to word splitting and, particularly relevant here, filename expansion.

Comment: Ah yes...that makes sense. I'm going to edit to add some clarity.